# Usage of SDK classes

Tags: java, sap-cloud-sdk

I am using SDK for Java, and I need to use one of the classes. However, I don´t know what exactly methods do, or I´d like to know which fields a get method will retrieve.

Looking [here] (https://help.sap.com/doc/b579bf8578954412aea2b458e8452201/1.0/en-US/index.html) in the help, I see the documentation, but I cannot find such information.

#### Question:

May I know where or how can I find this information?

BR,
Pietro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly. If you're talking about VDM entities (e.g. BusinessPartner, SalesOrder), the mapping should be straight-forward. There are service classes that mirror the OData APIs of SAP S/4HANA Cloud (see also api.sap.com), which have methods like `getAllEntities` or `getEntityByKey`, which will return you that `Entity` as a class. So by looking at the documentation of the respective class, you should see what you're getting back.

In case you're not talking about VDM entities, could you please give an example of a case where you're unable to find this information?